# doubts about python3 absolute imports

Tags: python, import

I know in python we can use absolute imports and these imports start at the root folder of the poject, example:

```
MyProject
 ├── module1.py
 ├── module2.py
 ├── package1
 | ├──__init__.py
 | └── module3.py
 └── package2
   ├── __init__.py
   └── module4.py
```

My question is, how does python know what the root folder is ?

Answer (score 0):

If you an use an absolute import you’ll have an import like `import Myproject.module1`, right?  Now, Python will walk `sys.path` directories.  The first directory of those w a `Myproject` subdir in it will use that Myproject subdir as the root for absolute imports of Myproject.